# PowerBI - How to improve query sent to SQL Server when using DirectQuery?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I'm running a Power BI dashboard using DirectQuery against an SQL server that has a sales table and a datetable, they are connected in the PBI datamodel using assume referential integrity to ensure inner joins. In this model I want to use time dimensions like MTD, YTD, R12M.

[image: Table structure]

Calculated measure for R12M

```
R12M = 
VAR
V_START_DATE = 
NEXTDAY(SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(LASTDATE(datetable[calendar_date])))
VAR
V_END_DATE = LASTDATE(datetable[calendar_date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(v_geo_tool_sales[sales_volume]);FILTER(ALL(datetable[calendar_date
    ]);datetable[calendar_date]>=V_START_DATE&&datetable[calendar_date]<=V_END_DATE))
```

SQL Generated by PBI

```
SELECT SUM([t0].[sales_volume])
 AS [a0]
FROM 
(
(select [$Table].[sold_to] as [sold_to],
    [$Table].[material] as [material],
    [$Table].[calendar_date] as [calendar_date],
    [$Table].[sales_volume] as [sales_volume]
from [dbo].[v_geo_tool_sales] as [$Table])
)
 AS [t0]
WHERE 
(
([t0].[calendar_date] IN (CAST( N'2017-01-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-31 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-31 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-31 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-31 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-31 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-31 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-27 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-23 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-10 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-26 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-06 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-17 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-30 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-11 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-21 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-05 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-15 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-09 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-20 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-19 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-31 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-13 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-24 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-25 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-04 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-18 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-12-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-12 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-05-29 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-04-22 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-09-03 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-10-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2016-11-02 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-03-16 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-28 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-08-14 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-02-07 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-07-08 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST( N'2017-06-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)))
)
```

The SQL query generated by PowerBI includes every single date that exists in the table instead of just filtering using the greater than and less than supplied in the measure.

Does anyone have any idea on how to re-write so that the query sent to SQL is a bit prettier?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but don't think you have any control over how DirectQuery translates to SQL.

Comment: Do you want to improve it because you think a WHERE DATE BETWEEN will perform better? Have you manually tested the "optimized" query to make sure it is actually faster? It sounds like you just want the query to be pretty. I don't understand why that's important.

Comment: Analyzing the query the prettier query actually yields less CPU load.

In statement
Estimate IO = 36,74
Estimate CPU = 37,81
Total cost = 636

Greater than and less then statement
Estimate IO = 36,74
Estimate CPU = 12,97
Total cost = 470

Comment: Only estimates? Possible to determine actual with `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;`?

Comment: Actuals show the same pattern, after running each query 5 times these are the stats

PB Query
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 28640 ms,  elapsed time = 734 ms.

Pretty query
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 21221 ms,  elapsed time = 573 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Storage Engine of SSAS is not able to handle complex comparison like > and <. They are compiled as IN (all possible values).

A clear pattern emerges immediately: reduce cardinality and the query will be simpler.

I suggest you to review the comparison in order to not perform both comparison on the date.
Instead, try something like:

```
FILTER(ALL(datetable[calendar_date
        ], datetable[year]);datetable[year]>=V_START_DATE&&datetable[calendar_date]<=V_END_DATE))
```

Note this is not the exact final solution but it is a suggestion to avoid using high cardinality fields in both comparison. If you use for example `year` for one of the comparison, you will reduce the cardinality and simplify the SQL query compiled.